# Unable to create new entry in production mode using Strapi

Tags: strapi

I'm using Strapi to generate REST api. I've created a content type (named article) - and using it in production mode & it is working fine. Now, I added a new content type (named vidtops), which works fine in development mode (no errors), but on switching to production mode, I'm unable to create a new entry in vidtops. However, the earlier endpoint (article) is working fine.

I'm using:-

strapi version = 3.0.0-alpha.25.2

on Ubuntu 18.04 (installed on AWS lightsail)

Node version = 10.15.3

npm version = 6.4.1

Mongodb version = 4.0.7

pm2 version = 3.4.0

This is the code I'm using for production launch:-

```
export NODE_ENV=production
pm2 start npm --name api -- start
```

while in dev mode, I use `strapi start`.

On clicking "add new entry", the spinner keeps running forever, here is the screenshot:-

[image: error screenshot]

The new content type is not available under 'Content manger' section, here is the screenshot:-
[image: content type not present]

I've tried many things in the last 48 hours, but it behaves abnormally. For once, I was able to create multiple content types and use them in production mode on a different server, with the same versions of the tools and same launch code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the schema management for the admin.
There is some issue on GitHub about that.

You will have to remove in your `core_store` table/collection the entry with `key` === `plugin_content-manager_schema`

Then restart your app and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Jims answer - (For anyone using Heroku cli & postgres) - these are the steps to follow :

- connect to db > `heroku pg:psql`
- Delete the key > `DELETE FROM core_store WHERE key = 'plugin_content-manager_schema'`
- Exit database > `\q`
- Restart Heroku > `heroku restart`

I will no doubt come back to this answer as I have to do it every time I create a new content type!